# how to create a private channel with stream chat flutter sdk?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an ecommerce app created with flutter ( under development),,
so I heard about the Stream_chat_flutter SDK ,, It is a really simple and easy solution to deal with, So my question is I have a user and a seller in my app and I want to make channel conversation between the seller and this particular user so when this user want to send a message to this seller in this time the channel will be created and the seller will be notified and get the message , How can I implement this with your Sdk?
note: that the seller can be contacted by many users .

(I have a authentication system with firebase.)

[Capture from the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcK53.png)

[Capture from the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HB1M.png)

Answer (score 0):

Channels are unique either by specifying a channel ID or a list of members in the create request.

If you want a private one on one channel between one user and a seller, use this:

```dart
client.channel("messaging", extraData: {"members": ["user_id", "seller_id"]});
```

See [here](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/flutter-dart/creating_channels/?language=dart#2.-creating-a-channel-for-a-list-of-members) for more info.
You can specify as many members as needed to create a group chat.